# oracle query find maximum salary with respect to jobrole

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have following tables

```
Employee24(Employeeid, firstname, jobroles)
Salary25(SalaryId, Employeeid, BasicSal, Allowences)
```

I want to find employee with max `salary(BasicSal + Allowences)` with respect to `jobroles`

```
  select e.firstname, e.lastname, 
   s.HighestSal, e.jobroles
 from Employee24 e inner join 
 (select employeeid, max(basicsal) as HighestSal
  from salary25 
  group by jobrole
 ) s
```

Comment: You typically GROUP BY the columns you select, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Also, the join condition is missing.

Comment: Qualify all column references! (I.e. `table.column`.)

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `keep` functionality -- a very powerful method in Oracle:

```
select e.jobrole, max(BasicSal + Allowances) as max_salary,
       max(e.EmployeeId) keep (dense_rank first order by BasicSal + Allowances desc) as employee_with_max
from salary25 s join
     employee25 e
     on s.Employeeid = e.Employeeid
group by e.jobrole;
```

Comment: thanks. i want to display e.firstname and e.lastname too. When i add these 2 columns it is giviiing me error 
ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression